# Can't apply AIX openssh fix

Tags: aix, openssh

I must begin saying that I'm not an AIX expert, just a beginner, but I have this issue/curiosity:
I'm trying to apply openssh fix for AIX :
5.3, 6.1, 7.1, 7.2  IV80743m9a.160127.epkg.Z openssh.base(6.0.0.6201 version)      key_w_fix

```
oslevel -s
7100-00-10-1334

lslpp -L|grep -i openssh.base
  openssh.base.client     6.0.0.6103    C     F    Open Secure Shell Commands
  openssh.base.server     6.0.0.6103    C     F    Open Secure Shell Server
```

And when I try installing (preview mode):

```
Verifying prerequisite file ...
Checking prerequisites ...

Prerequisite Number: 1
   Fileset: openssh.base.server
   Minimal Level: 6.0.0.6201
   Maximum Level: 6.0.0.6201
   Actual Level: 6.0.0.6103
   Type: PREREQ
   Requisite Met: no

Prerequisite Number: 2
   Fileset: openssh.base.client
   Minimal Level: 6.0.0.6201
   Maximum Level: 6.0.0.6201
   Actual Level: 6.0.0.6103
   Type: PREREQ
   Requisite Met: no

emgr: 0645-050 Prerequisite number 1 did not pass all checks. Please see
details above.
emgr: 0645-050 Prerequisite number 2 did not pass all checks. Please see
details above.

emgr: 0645-035 Efix package did not pass all preview checks.
```

Install fails because the minumum prerequisite level is the one that I must install.

Any ideas ?

I was preparing to upgrade AIX to TL1 and try again.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All of the TL would be overkill. You have an interim fix that only applies to the latest cumulative maintenance.

You just need to grab 6.0.0.6201 from FixCentral

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install something that is not a regular update.

The point is: why are you trying to install an ifix? Is your real intention? If you just want to update openssh, you better get a regular update.